# Check value in before delete oracle trigger and then insert in another table

Tags: oracle, triggers

Currently we have a trigger on tbl_number.
It is as follows,

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_EXAMPLE
BEFORE DELETE
ON TBL_NUMBER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


-- Insert record into TBL_NUMBER _DUMMY table
INSERT INTO TBL_NUMBER _DUMMY
 ( NAME, NO_OF_PEOPLE)
  VALUES
 ( :old.NAME, :old.NO_OF_PEOPLE)
 END;
```

Now we want to modify trigger 
and check value NO_OF_People in original table tbl_number 
and if it is (-1), we want to put 0 (or null) in column NO_of_People of table tbl_number_dummy.

Any pointers for it would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Adi

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO TBL_NUMBER_DUMMY
 ( NAME, NO_OF_PEOPLE)
  VALUES
 ( :old.NAME, decode(:old.NO_OF_PEOPLE, -1, 0, :old.NO_OF_PEOPLE)
 END;
```

Or, if you want to insert into  TBL_NUMBER _DUMMY only if NO_OF_PEOPLE = -1,

```
CASE WHEN :old.NO_OF_PEOPLE = -1 THEN
INSERT INTO TBL_NUMBER _DUMMY
 ( NAME, NO_OF_PEOPLE)
  VALUES
 ( :old.NAME, :old.NO_OF_PEOPLE)
ELSE null;
END;
```

UPDATE(response to comment):

```
INSERT INTO TBL_NUMBER_DUMMY
 ( NAME, NO_OF_PEOPLE)
  VALUES
 ( :old.NAME, case when :old.NO_OF_PEOPLE < 0 then 0; else :old.NO_OF_PEOPLE; end)
 END;
```

or, with decode

```
INSERT INTO TBL_NUMBER_DUMMY
 ( NAME, NO_OF_PEOPLE)
  VALUES
 ( :old.NAME, decode(sign(:old.NO_OF_PEOPLE), -1, 0, :old.NO_OF_PEOPLE)
 END;
```

:)

And yes you can insert null into a number column, except the situation when the column has a  NOT NULL. constraint.

Comment: tHANKS ! i needed to insert it into dummy table every time not just (-1). And first thing worked ! And one more thing, how to change no-of-people to 0 when original number of people is any negative number ? and can we insert it as null in new dummy table ? column type is number.